# Meteor: serializing and deserializing javascript and mongo objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, deserialization

When storing a javascript object in MongoDB, all the methods are stripped away and the object  has type Object. Additionally, I must remove any circular reference of objects inside this javascript object for the serialization to not loop infinitely.

To get back the javascript object, I essentially need to construct a new object using the original type and copy the data from the mongo object. Is there any clean way to do this without having to write custom deserialize and clone functions to do it? Here is a not-so-clean way I am using, that I thought would be robust to rapid changes of the Library's objects' fields.

```
Library.deserialize = function(obj)
{
    if (obj instanceof Object && !(obj instanceof Function)) 
    {
        var newObj = {};
        var Constructor = Library[obj.CLASS_NAME];

        if (Constructor) 
        {
            newObj = new Constructor;
        }

        for (var prop in obj) 
        {
            var subObj = obj[prop];

            if (Array.isArray(subObj)) 
            {
                var newSubObj = [];

                subObj.forEach(function(subObjItem)
                {
                    newSubObj.push(Library.deserialize(subObjItem));
                });
            } 
            else if (subObj instanceof Object) 
            {
                var newSubObj = Library.deserialize(subObj);
            } 
            else 
            { // a Primitive??
                var newSubObj = subObj;
            }

            newObj[prop] = newSubObj;
        }

        // special case: adding back circular ref
        if (newObj.addBackCircularRef)
        {
            newObj.addBackCircularRef();
        }

        return newObj;
    }
    else 
    {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

The problem is that this will not work if I have objects not in the Library, and for objects in the Library, it requires me to annotate them with class name like this

```
Library.Book = function(title) 
{
  this.title = title;
  this.CLASS_NAME = 'Book';
}
```

Comment: When meteor stores a document, it's seralized as [EJSON](https://www.meteor.com/ejson) which can't include things like functions and circular references. To instantiate a new instance after a [find](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) you should use a transform. See [this video](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-transforming-collection-documents) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this. I should use it.